# My footer does not keep at bottom and it leaves a blank space behind

Tags: html, css

My footer always float within table list, Please see my page here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YBmH/)

```
#footer {
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 20px;
background-color: #666600;
padding: 20px;
```

}

I tried to put position:fixed & bottom:0 in #footer but it does not help. I want to make the footer stay exact where it is with no blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give #sideber to position:relative

```
    #sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #333333;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    bottom:0
}
```

[Jsifiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YBmH/2/)